# ASP .NET UpdatePanel in dynamically loaded control

Tags: .net, load, controls, updatepanel, loadcontrol

Currently we have an UpdatePanel containing a Panel as follows:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="panel" runat="server">
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

We then dynamically load a custom control using LoadControl() into the Panel. To complicate matters the custom control contains its own UpdatePanel.

The problem I am facing at the moment is - how I update the inner UpdatePanel without having the outer UpdatePanel refresh? The UpdateMode is set to Conditional on both. Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `ChildrenAsTriggers=false` for the parent update panel?

http://www.asp.net/ajax/tutorials/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

> Automatic child trigger inclusion can
>   also be disabled (so that child
>   controls that create postbacks do not
>   automatically trigger partial renders)
>   by setting the ChildrenAsTriggers
>   property to false. This allows you the
>   greatest flexibility in assigning
>   which specific controls may invoke a
>   page render, and is recommended, so
>   that a developer will opt-in to
>   respond to an event, rather than
>   handling any events that may arise.
>
> Note that when UpdatePanel controls
>   are nested, when the UpdateMode is set
>   to Conditional, if the child
>   UpdatePanel is triggered, but the
>   parent is not, then only the child
>   UpdatePanel will refresh. However, if
>   the parent UpdatePanel is refreshed,
>   then the child UpdatePanel will also
>   be refreshed.